# Grails: Where do I handle a domain class property that can have two different representations?

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am programming a way of displaying products that I get from a MySQL database based on user input. My products have a property (size) that can either be represented by a string, by an object of the type Size (another domain class holding three float-values) or be missing alltogether. 
Currently my Product-Class has one property for each representation, both of which are nullable. In my view I have one specific place where this property should be displayed.
Now my question is, where do I handle the problem of determining which representation I have for a specific object?

I would be able to include an if-condition in my gsp-template but that seems to be bad practice.
I would be able to have the service that does the query handle the results and build a single size-property to pass to the template but that doesn't seem right either.
Is the problem in my database design?
Do I have to change my domain-model?

I am sorry for the very general question, I can definitely change that once I know where exactly I need to change something. Thanks a lot already!

Comment: There are many different ways of answering this, you could pass object directly from gsp into a taglib and reuse taglib method in all cases where gsp would be doing logic - not a lot wrong with doing basic ifs in a gsp. The alternative would be to write your query in `HQL` and using `case statements` you could decide based on result output within query what to display. https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/reports/QueueReportService.groovy#L448-L458 using something like when object is null do something etc

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem would be to use an additional [transient](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html) field that would be used in your views, but would not be persisted in your database.

```
class Product {
    String sizeString
    Size sizeSize

    getSize() { sizeString ?: sizeSize.toString() }

    static transients = ['size']
}
```